# Stop macro from repeating when using Application.OnTime

Tags: excel, vba

By using the below code **RefreshData** I run **mg** macro every 10 secs.

I'm unable to stop **stoprefresh** which is assigned to a square shape.

```
Sub RefreshData()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "mg", , True
End Sub

Sub stoprefresh()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "mg", , False
End Sub

Sub mg()

    ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = "Running"

    Call RefreshData

End Sub
```

Comment: _"However, i'm unable to stop by using the below code stoprefresh"_ .. At what point do you make a call to `stoprefresh`?

Comment: By click of a button..

Comment: You want to [edit] that crucial bit of information into your question? And describe what type of button -- on a userform, ActiveX control button, etc.?

Comment: updated my question please refer! Thank you :)

Comment: Are you sure it's actually "running"? You don't have something in your code to remove the "running" cell... Something like `ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = "Finished"` in your `stoprefresh` code. Which personally, I'd rather use `Application.StatusBar = "Running"` and `Application.StatusBar = False`, but that's just personal preference I suppose.

Comment: Nop i dont need anything like finished. Just that timing update should be stopped..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Option Explicit

Dim iTimerSet As Double
Sub RefreshData()
    iTimerSet = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
    Application.OnTime iTimerSet, "mg", , True
End Sub
Sub stoprefresh()
    'On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime iTimerSet, "mg", , False
End Sub

Sub mg()
    ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = "Running"
    Call RefreshData
End Sub
```

> **[Cancelling a scheduled Procedure](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/macros/application-ontime.htm)** 
>   It is possible to cancel a procedure that has been scheduled to run but you need to know the
>   exact date and time it was scheduled for. To cancel a scheduled
>   procedure you must know the "EarliestTime" it was scheduled for.
>   Exactly the same syntax except you set the schedule paramater to
>   False. This tells the application to cancel the schedule.